# get � when for special characters using gettext and smarty

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, translation, gettext

I am using `$encoding = 'utf-8';` in gettext and in my html code i have set `<meta charset="utf-8">`. I have also set utf-8 in my .po files, but I still get � when I write æøå! What can be wrong?

Comment: Did you save the page as UTF-8?

Comment: What do you mean? I saved the page as .php or .tpl

Comment: Do you use any functions like `substr()`? If yes then replace them by adding `mb_` at front. http://dk.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see how the values you mention are at the byte level.

I copied the `æøå` from your question and `ï¿½` from your title. The reason for `ï¿½` is that I had to use a Windows console application to fetch the title of your question and its codepage was Windows 1252 (copying from the browser gave me [`Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)).

In a script encoded in UTF-8, this gives:

```
<?php
$s = 'æøå';
$s2 = 'ï¿½';

echo "s iso-8859-1 ", @reset(unpack("H*", mb_convert_encoding($s, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8"))), "\n";
echo "s2 win-1252  ", @reset(unpack("H*", mb_convert_encoding($s, "WINDOWS-1252", "UTF-8"))), "\n";
```

```
s iso-8859-1 e6f8e5
s2 win-1252  e6f8e5
```

So the byte representation matches. The problem here is that when you write `æøå` either:

- You're writing it in ISO-8859-1, instead of UTF-8. Check your text editor.
- The value is being converted from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 (unlikely)

Comment: Artefacto: Why do you see a `ï¿½` in the title? This page is declared to be encoded with UTF-8, you need to change the encoding manually to ISO 8859-1 to have this output.

Comment: @Gumbo You're right; it didn't occur to me, but it works (at least in Opera 10.61/Windows). By the way, I find it odd that changing the encoding manually to ISO-8859-1 makes the browser interpret it as win-1252, but I guess it's just a compatibility quirky (I think the HTML 5 spec specifically says to interpret pages that declare being ISO-8859-1 as win-1252).

Comment: @Gumbo My mistake, those are all valid iso-8859-1 characters.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set this

bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8");

Otherwise you will get the � character